# column placement

Tags: tables

I need to set the table look like this : [image]

with 3 variables under 'Nominal Parameters and four under 'Coefficients'. So far I have this :

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| |l|c|c|c|c|c|c|| } 
 \hline
 \multicolumn{7}{|c||}{Nominal parameters}{Coefficients}\\
 \hline
 1000$C_{E,nom}$ & $v_{s,nom}$ & $a_{CE}$ & $b_{CE}$ & $c_{CE}$ & $d_{CE}$ & $k_{CE}$\\ \hline
 10.6863 & 15 & 0.333 & 10.2 & 0.07 & -15 & -0.06\\\hline
   \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Coefficients of specific resistance\cite{Sui}}
   \label{tab:specificres}
  \end{table}
```

How can I fix this? 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to tex.stack....

Comment: Please, always provide complete document naming MWE (Minimal Working Example) which we can compile. In preamble of it are important inforamtion about your document, which we from your code fragment can not extract ... and also need to type part of document, which you already have. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below tag may fix your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 \hline
& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Nominal parameters} &\multicolumn{3}{|c}{Coefficients}\\
 \hline
 1000$C_{E,nom}$ & $v_{s,nom}$ & $a_{CE}$ & $b_{CE}$ & $c_{CE}$ & $d_{CE}$ & $k_{CE}$\\ \hline
 10.6863 & 15 & 0.333 & 10.2 & 0.07 & -15 & -0.06\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Coefficients of specific resistance\cite{Sui}}
   \label{tab:specificres}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it does! thank you so much

Comment: @Nikhil Happy to hear the suggestion works you... If the suggestion suits with you, then accept this answer by clicking the tick mark symbol...

Answer (score 1):

And here is your tabular if you want to try the [cals-package](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\let\nc=\nullcell      % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40 *4)\relax} % Table columns relative to margins 
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 7)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 5)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 5)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 5)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 5)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 5)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 5)\relax}%
        }
% Layout elements
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{1.2pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{0pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\abovedisplayskip=-1pt
\belowdisplayskip=-1pt

% R1 Heading
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}
    \def\cals@rs@width{1.2pt}
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}  % Remove left side bearing
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Nominal parameters}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Coefficients}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
\mdseries}
% R2
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
    \cell{}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 1000$C_{E,nom}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil$v_{s,nom}$ }
    \alignC\cell{\vfil$a_{CE}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil$b_{CE}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil$c_{CE}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil$d_{CE}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil$k_{CE}$}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
 %R3
\brow
    \setlength\cals@paddingL{0pt}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil Value}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 10.6863}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 15}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil 0.333}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil10.2}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil0.07}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $-$15}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $-$0.06}
    \setlength\cals@paddingR{0pt}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
\makeatother

\end{calstable}

  \caption{Coefficients of specific resistance\cite{Sui}}
   \label{tab:specificres}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

desired design of table -- according to my taste -- is not look nice. I would design it as follows:

[image]

Above table is written by use if `booktabs` and `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\CE{\mathit{CE}}
\newcommand\nom{\mathrm{nom}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{6}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Nominal parameters} 
        &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Coefficients}        \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
$1000C_{E,\nom}$    & $v_{s,\nom}$  & $a_{\CE}$ 
    & $b_{\CE}$ & $c_{\CE}$ & $d_{\CE}$ & $k_{\CE}$ \\ 
    \midrule
 10.6863        & 15            & 0.333 
    & 10.2      & 0.07      & -15       & -0.06     \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Coefficients of specific resistance \cite{Sui}}
   \label{tab:specificres}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I suspect that your table has more rows with numbers similar to those in the showed one. In this case I would consider to use `S` column type from  `siunitx` package. To show how to use it, you need to provide contents of some more rows (if they exist) to confirm my suspicion.